# Android canvas : drawing effect "inside" a path

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, effect

I'd like to draw an effect *inside* a path on a canvas (path is polyline), but I cannot figure out what to use... 
Path Effect seems useless.

I am trying to render something like this...

[image: Example of path effect]

Many thisnks in advance.

JM

Comment: I'm afraid you have to draw it by yourself, PathMeasure could be useful in this case

Comment: Would it be simpler if I just draw a translucent band inside the path (instead of the dashes) ?

Comment: still you cannot do it in one api call